# Flutter textfield how to position floating label and error label

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, textfield

I have a flutter design

1. when user selects textfield should fill with blue color then floating label padding above the border and textfield content padding should change.
2. When the textfield has an error both floating label and error label change the color and I have to position them.

Can someone help me how to achieve this as Reusable TextField

Please refer to the image.

[image: design]

**Image with Animation**

[image: Image with Animation]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Comment: I don't have any code snippet available I am kind of new to Flutter still learning

Comment: Does the below answer satisfy you? Hope he will give an update

Comment: Yes kind of but not fully can you refer to gif and help me. I need to achieve something like gif

Comment: I think question update breaks his answer,

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Rather then using `label` text I would consider using `Text()` above your `TextFormField()`. You can try this code below to get your result

```
FocusNode _focus = FocusNode();
  bool _isValidate = true;

  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 11),
                  child: Text("Field Value",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color:
                              _focus.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.white))),
              TextFormField(
                focusNode: _focus,
                onTap: () {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus();
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor:
                        _focus.hasFocus ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent),
              ),
              Divider(),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 11),
                  child: Text("Field Value",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: _isValidate ? Colors.white : Colors.red))),
              Form(
                key: _key,
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                      errorStyle:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                  validator: (val) {
                    if (val!.length >= 5) {
                      setState(() {
                        _isValidate = false;
                      });
                      return "Field Value";
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        _isValidate = true;
                      });
                      return null;
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Divider(),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final form = _key.currentState;
                    form!.validate();
                  },
                  child: Text("Submit"))
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of right but It should animate I have added the gif could you please have a look and help me out

Comment: Well your first requirement can be fulfilled but in second one if you use label then corner border will be hidden.

Comment: I am able to complete the first requirement but need animations

Comment: As I told you you can get animation with background color but with border it will not look the same.